# The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vagrant

I have a small problem with setting up my working environment after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. Vagrant version is 2.0.0.

Vagrant File

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  # config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8888

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant-nfs", type: :nfs, mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc' ,'actimeo=2']
  config.bindfs.bind_folder "/vagrant-nfs", "/srv/bspotted.net/app", :owner => "vagrant", :group => "vagrant"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.15"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "bspotted", "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL

   # Ansible provisioner.
   config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.version = "2.3.2.0"
    ansible.install_mode = "pip"
    ansible.provisioning_path = "/srv/bspotted.net/app"
    ansible.playbook = "orchestration/vagrant.yml"
    ansible.verbose = "vvv"
   end
end
```

For the record I have an older version Ubuntu 16.10 on my other laptop and everything is working properly, this is the output of the vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log command [here](https://gist.github.com/Copser/84227e2879836e5ea1f90a7d79633c50).

Everything fall apart when setup reach

```
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
```

after aprox 5 minutes, it will show

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp,rw,vers=3,tcp,fsc,actimeo=2 192.168.33.1:/home/copser/Documents/Bspotted /vagrant-nfs

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved after I've changed the version of nfs,

```
`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant-nfs", type: :nfs, mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc' ,'actimeo=2']`
```

to

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant-nfs", type: :nfs, mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=4', 'tcp', 'fsc' ,'actimeo=2']
```

just to make it clear I've changed `vers=3` to `vers=4`, and no everything is working fine. You can check my correspondence with vagrant contributors [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9918).